# jquery error with return bool value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie to javascript and i cant return the boolean value of the function.. i am validating the textboxes for null and return false if its empty help please?

```
validateForm : function() {
    $('.requiredField :input').each(function(){
        if ('input[type=text]'){
            if($(this).val().length === 0){
                    $(this).addClass('warning');
                    var  errorMsg = $('<br /><span>Please Fill in the TextBox</span>').addClass('warning');
                    errorMsg.insertAfter(this);
                    $(errorMsg).css('color','red');
                    $('.warning').css('border-color','red');
            //$(this).focus(function(){
                //$(this).removeClass('warning');   
                //$(this).parent().children('span').remove();
                //$(this).parent().children('br').remove();         
            //});
                    return false;
                }
            else 
                return true;
            }
        }); 

},
Form.validateForm(); // call to the function
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: @Kaf no messages or no error either

Comment: return false to where? You're just executing the function.

Comment: What is the question specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `return`ing from *inside* the `.each()`.  That doesn't make your function return a value.

In an `.each()` loop, `return false;` is like using `break;`, and `return true;` is like using `continue;`.

You need to declare a variable *outside* of the `.each()`, set its value *inside* the loop, then return it *after* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

check this line

```
if ('input[type=text]'){
```

it should be

```
 if($('input[type=text]')){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.requiredField :input').each(function(){
var i=$(this).val();

if(i == '' || i == null)
 {
 //execute your codes
 return false;
 }else{
 return true;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to write a plugin? Try the following code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.validateForm = function()
    {
        var formID = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#'+ formID +' input[type=submit]').click(function(e)
        { 

            e.preventDefault();

            $('input[type=text]').each(function(){

                if($(this).val().length === 0){                 

                        $(this).addClass('warning');
                        var  errorMsg = $('<span>Please Fill in the TextBox</span>').addClass('warning');
                        errorMsg.insertAfter(this);
                        $(errorMsg).css('color','red');
                        $('.warning').css('border-color','red');          
                        return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @RocketHazmat, your function needs to aggregate results from the inside loop and have a single exit point in order to validate (and add the css classes/html elements) **every** input.

You need to do something like this:

```
validateForm : function () {

        var invalidInputs = [];

        // only test the type='text' inputs
        $('.requiredField :input[type="text"]').each(function () {

            // if there is no value
            if ($(this).val() == undefined || $(this).val().length == 0) {

                $(this).addClass('warning');
                var errorMsg = $('<br /><span>Please Fill in the TextBox</span>').addClass('warning');
                errorMsg.insertAfter(this);
                $(errorMsg).css('color','red');
                $('.warning').css('border-color','red');

                // add the invalid input to an array
                invalidInputs.push($(this));
            }
        }); 

        // The form is only valid for no invalid inputs were found.
        return invalidInputs.length == 0;
    }
```